# viewModelScope not cancelled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

After watching [Sean's explanation on Android (Google I/O'19)](https://youtu.be/BOHK_w09pVA?t=1425) I've tried the same:

```
init{
    viewModelScope.launch {
        Timber.i("coroutine awake")
        while (true){
            delay(2_000)
            Timber.i("another round trip")
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `onCleared` it's called when the activity is killed but not when it's put in background ("when we move away from the Activity...", background is "moving away" imho ^^).
And I get the following output:

```
> ---- Activity in Foreground
> 12:41:10.195  TEST: coroutine awake
> 12:41:12.215  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:14.231  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:16.245  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:18.259  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:20.270  TEST: another round trip
> ----- Activity in Background (on onCleared not fired)
> 12:41:22.283  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:24.303  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:26.320  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:28.353  TEST: another round trip
> 12:41:30.361  TEST: another round trip
> ----- Activity in Foreground
> 12:41:30.369  TEST: coroutine awake
```

How can I solve this?

1 - Move the code from `init` to a `suspend fun start()` called by the activity inside a `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted`?

I get the same result. I thought `lifecycleScope` would cancel its child coroutines when it went to background, but I get the same Timber output with this approach.

2 - Change my ViewModel code to:

```
private lateinit var job: Job

suspend fun startEmitting() {
    job = viewModelScope.launch {
        Timber.i("coroutine awake")
        while (true){
            delay(2_000)
            Timber.i("another round trip")
        }
    }
}
fun cancelJob(){
    if(job.isActive){
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

And, in my Activity:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.startEmitting()
    }
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    viewModel.cancelJob()
}
```

Well it works but isn't the `viewModelScope` purpose to manage the `CoroutineScope` for me? I hate this cancelJob logic.

What's the best approach to deal with this?

Comment: ViewModel is not aware of activity lifecycle, it will only react to activity being destroyed. You can move your logic to a `LiveData` object, then you'll be able to react to `onActive` `onInactive` callbacks.

Comment: you mean by using liveData{} ktx? because actually this coroutine calls `_someLiveData.value = ...` each loop. Thing is, if I send the app to background the loop continues. Of course the UI doesn't react to that, but shouldn't we avoid the extra computation of the loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin can't cancel an infinite operation for you. You need to call `isActive` somewhere. For example: `while(isActive)`.

Comment: That was the missing piece! Obrigado Jose :)

Comment: I found something curious: If I have the Activity in foreground every 2s I get a log. If I touch home/options button the app goes to background and it still logs every 2s aprox 3/4 times. After that it randomly logs at no precise time. Ex: it can log after 20s, 2s, 6s. Any particular reason? I thought `isActive` would always return false in background.

Comment: I have the `isActive` in my test, but the test keeps running, am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `LiveData` class instead of using `MutableLiveData`.

When you do that you can override methods that explicitly notify you if there are any active listeners.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(){
    val liveData = CustomLiveData(viewModelScope)

    class CustomLiveData(val scope) : LiveData<Int>(){
        private counter = 0
        private lateinit var job: Job

        override fun onActive() {
            job = scope.launch {
                Timber.i("coroutine awake")
                while (true){
                    delay(2_000)
                    Timber.i("another round trip")
                    postValue(counter++)
                }
        }

        override fun onInactive() {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside your `Activity` you no longer need to explicitly call any start/pause as `LiveData` will automatically begin and cancel coroutine depending on observers state.