# Why my canceled coroutine job still running?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an experiment coroutine function as below

```
       runBlocking {
            Log.d("Track", "Launching...")
            val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                repeat(2000) {
                    repeat(2000) {
                        Log.d("Track", "Suspending...")
                    }
                }
                Log.d("Track", "Done...")
            }

            Log.d("Track", "Launched...")
            delay(100)
            Log.d("Track", "Canceling...")
            job.cancel()
            Log.d("Track", "Canceled...")
        }
```

When I run it, even after cancel, the coroutine continue running as log below

```
Track: Launching...
Track: Launched...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Canceling...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Canceled...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Suspending...
Track: Suspending...
:
: (a lot more suspending)
:
Track: Done...
```

Why can't I get my coroutine canceled? Should I put a `yield()` just to check from time to time to get it canceled in case?

Comment: `if (!isActive) return@launch; Log.d("Track", "Suspending...")`

Comment: Please help me for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473066/removed-recycler-item-shows-up-again-after-deleting-other

Comment: I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58099407/1423773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the cancelation is cooperative, as mentioned in [Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). We'll need to have [either `yield()` or check for `isActive`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable)

Comment: If you are calling suspending function inside there, you don't need to. You only need these when you having blocking piece of code, so to give the event loop time to check if the cancellation notice have been received.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu  it's inaccurate to say "calling suspending function" is enough for cancellation to work, most user written suspension functions don't have that coorperative behavior, but the built in functions like delay do

Comment: @ssynhtn Yep, thanks for correction!